# $A_{N-1}$ Singularities in a K3 Surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, gauge-theory, k3-surfaces

I have some understanding of the typical $A_{N-1}$ singularities arising as the orbifold $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{N}$.  Of course, you can blow up the origin to get a bunch of rigid, rational curves linked together just as in the Dynkin diagram.  I've seen in a few places people discussing "*$A_{N-1}$ singularities inside a K3 surface*."

I was hoping someone could explain to me how such a thing is constructed.  I know $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is a Calabi-Yau just like a K3 surface, so do you just naïvely take an orbifold quotient of a K3 surface by $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$, and then blow up to get a smooth Calabi-Yau with a bunch of exceptional $\mathbb{P}^{1}$'s?  I'm unsure how to define this group action though; it is clean in the case of the plane.

Also, can this be done with any K3 surface? I know the rational curves in a K3 are rigid (i.e. they move in a zero dimensional family) and in particular, I think not every K3 even contains rational curves. So I guess if you take one of these quotients of a K3 without rational curves, you blow up to arrive at a smooth K3 which indeed has rational curves?

(BTW, this came to me in the context of physics: apparently, in Type IIA string theory, if you compactify on such a K3 as above, after blowing up the singularities you get a $\mathcal{N}=4\,U(N)$ gauge theory in six dimensions.)

Comment: Let me just comment that there is way to get such singularities other than by quotients: namely, _degenerating_ a smooth $K3$ surface. So you could start with a smooth quartic surface in $\mathbf P^3$, or an intersection of a quadric and a cubic in $\mathbf P^4$, etc, and degenerate. I'm not an expert, but it seems plausible this leads to different types of singularities than one gets by quotients.

Comment: By the way, when you resolve an $A_n$ singularity to get a smooth projective surface $S$, it is a fact that the exceptional curves of the resolution are all linearly independent in $\operatorname Pic(S)$. In particular the number of such curves is bounded by the rank of $\operatorname Pic(S)$. This is a very simple reason why the $n$ that can occur on a $K3$ surface are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good example is the Kummer K3 surface. Start with a complex two-torus $\mathbb C^2 / \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice of rank four. Then quotient by the $\mathbb Z_2$ automorphism:
$$ (x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y),$$
where $x, y \in \mathbb C$ are the natural complex coordinates on the two-torus.

This automorphism has 16 isolated fixed points. After performing the quotient, you are left with 16 $A_1$ singularities at those fixed points.

If you blow up those singularities, which resolves them into rational curves with self-intersection $-2$, you end up with a smooth K3 surface. Indeed, it is simple to check that the canonical divisor remains trivial after the resolution.

Of course, such a K3 surface is very special. Notably, its Picard rank is at least 16. The generic (non-algebraic) K3 has Picard rank zero. So you shouldn't expect a "neighbouring point in the K3 moduli space" to also be of Kummer type.

If you start with a two-torus of a special shape, e.g. a product of two elliptic curves with complex structure parameter $\tau = i$ or $\exp(2\pi i /3)$, it's actually possible to quotient by discrete groups larger than $\mathbb Z_2$ to get singular K3s. You can end up with orbifold singularities of $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_5$, $D_4$, $D_5$ and $E_6$ type. Katrin Wendland has classified all the possibilities in this very nice physics paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0010281.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I'm understanding the jist of that paper, we actually cannot get $A_{N}$ singularities for $N$ larger than 5?  Also that seems to be specifically in this case you describe where you construct it from a two-torus.  Can you get any $A_{N}$ singularity in some K3?  Maybe it's just not such an explicit construction, as the one you gave above.

Comment: @spietro Here are my thoughts: if you're going to get a K3 by quotienting and resolving another surface, then this "original surface" must either be $\mathbb C^2 / \Lambda$ or another K3. Katrin Wendland has classified all possibilities starting from $\mathbb C^2 / \Lambda$. So that leaves us to think about whether we can get K3's by quotienting OTHER K3s.

Comment: As it happens, discrete automorphism of K3's are strongly constrained by the holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point formula. You can only get discrete automorphisms of order $\leq 8$. The number of fixed points of these automorphisms have been classified, and it's possible to work out the nature of the singularities by looking at the eigenvalues of the action of the automorphism on the tangent space at the fixed points. See Table 1 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2671

Comment: So the conclusion is that if you quotient a K3 by a discrete group generated by ONE element, then you can get singularities of type $A_{n-1}$ for $n = 1, \dots, 8$. Presumably it's possible to get $D$ and $E$ type singularities by quotienting a K3 by a discrete group with multiple generators, but I haven't worked it out. For that, I recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04942, section 3.2, and the references within.